# making node.js net client

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, client

In all the examples of creating a client for node.js built-in net module I don't see how they get net to run on the client with out downloading it??

surely if my client-side code starts like this:

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect({port: 8124},function(){
   console.log('client connected');
   client.write('world!\r\n');
   });
```

then first i must write:

```
<script src="some strange node path to net ??"></script>
```

am i correct? how do I do this? btw: node.js is installed in my root on my server not local

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Call a node server from a browser, or from another node instance?

Comment: i want to talk: client to server and vice versa

Comment: not with socket.io (i don't like voodoo) i want to understand by building something simple myself

Comment: Are you asking where the `net` module is stored?

Comment: yes and also how to use it to ceate the client in the browser for two way communication... im also looking at ajax and the http module scratching my head!

Comment: http is built on top of net? and keep alive is less expensive?

Comment: i really don't like the look of the code with all the headers in http, i like the look of net it is simple

Comment: @BenMuircroft Node.JS doesn't really run inside the browser, it runs on a server, so requiring 'net' in the browser doesn't (unless there's a corresponding browser framework I don't know of) make much sense.

Comment: ok, i think that it makes sense to send/receive ajax calls to the net module, but i don't see any examples online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there's a bit of confusion here. The client example code you're showing is meant to run in node, not in the browser. That makes node a client of another (node or otherwise) TCP server.

If you want node to be the client and connect to another server over TCP, then run the code you're pasting. The `net` module is bundled with node, you're good to go.

If, however, you want your browser to talk to a node server then this would have to be over websockets (a streaming binary protocol over http, this is not plain-vanilla TCP). You would have to have a websockets module in the server, not plain `net`.

Just to be clear: `net` is simply node's interface to TCP sockets.

Comment: I am very confused because of one web page http://rhuno.com/flashblog/2011/05/22/tutorial-socket-server-with-flash-and-node-js/2/ (btw, I am not intending to use flash). all i see here is 1) bidirectional communication. 2) only net module. Someone please explain how. This is messing my head up! google says nothing on stupid asp.net stuff nothing for node.js unless you want express or socket.io

Comment: btw: that is page 2 of 3